# Java PathMatcher: why ** doesn't work for zero folders?

Tags: java, glob

I'm trying to match relative paths using a PathMatcher. A very common case is to use a pattern like `**/foo.php` to match all files named `foo.php` whatever is the folder they are in.
But I found a behavior that look wrong to me, when the file is actually in no folders:

```java
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PathMatcherTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testMatch("foo.php", Paths.get("foo.php"));
    testMatch("foo.php", Paths.get("sub/foo.php"));
    testMatch("**/foo.php", Paths.get("sub/foo.php"));
    testMatch("**/foo.php", Paths.get("foo.php"));
  }

  private static void testMatch(String pattern, Path path) {
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
    if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
      System.out.println(pattern + " matches " + path);
    } else {
      System.out.println(pattern + " doesn't matches " + path);
    }
  }

}
```

produces:

```
foo.php matches foo.php // OK
foo.php doesn't matches sub/foo.php // OK
**/foo.php matches sub/foo.php // OK
**/foo.php doesn't matches foo.php // KO, why ????
```

Why is the GLOB pattern `**/foo.php` not matching `foo.php`? Am I misreading the spec, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-):

> The `**` characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory boundaries.

With your pattern `**/foo.php` it's easy to see why it's not working. Because `**` can be empty, the matcher essentially checks if `foo.php` matches `/foo.php` (which it clearly should not, one is located in the current folder, the other in the root).

To fix this: You can use a subpattern to match the case where the file resides in no folder. You can achieve this by changing your pattern to `{foo.php,**/foo.php}`

> The `{ }` characters are a group of subpatterns, where the group matches if any subpattern in the group matches. The "," character is used to separate the subpatterns. Groups cannot be nested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was about to say it was still looking like a bug to me (using string matching under the hood, while it should consider path segments). But I just did a quick test in bash, and I have the same behavior. `ls **/foo.php` doesn't return a match for file in the current dir... So I think it is just me having a bad expectation :)

Comment: @JulienH. glad I could help you. I think of `**/foo.php` like this: `**` matches anything regardless of directory (could also be empty), but it must be followed by `/foo.php`, so, at least for me, it's clear why `foo.php` wouldn't match.

Comment: What I found strange is that there is no simple way to look for a specific filename, whatever is the folder (recursive search).